# Encrypted Traffic Test in Mobile

Tags: encryption

how to check the SSL/TLS encryption of my mobile application.is there any way to check and watch encrypted traffic in my cell

i m using android phone..is there any procedure to check the encryption of my mobile apps

Comment: http://www.bolet.org/TestSSLServer/

Comment: I think he wants to test client configuration @raz.

Comment: @neilsmithline ah I misunderstood

Comment: your question is unclear as to what you want to know.

Answer (score 0):

Use a debugging proxy on a computer that allows remote connections and configure your Android to access it. See this [reference](http://www.cantoni.org/2013/11/06/capture-android-web-traffic-fiddler).